# The Herbert Voß series of LaTeX books

Tags: books

Yesterday I spent a lot of money ordering four titles of the Herbert Voß series of LaTeX books from Amazon. The books that I've ordered are:

1. Einführung in LaTeX
2. Mathematiksatz mit LaTeX
3. Tabellen mit LaTex
4. Bibliografien mit LaTeX

However, now I realize that perhaps books 2-4 may simply comprise of selected chapters of book 1. Unfortunately, I can't directly verify this, because Amazon do not supply a See Inside feature for these books.

Would anyone who is familiar with these books, or at least has access to them, please let me know if it looks like books 2-4 are merely excerpts from book 1, or if they seem to have significant content that sets them apart from 1 and merits purchasing them separately?

Comment: You can find samples at lehmanns: e.g. https://www.lehmanns.de/shop/mathematik-informatik/34994590-9783865418432-bibliografien-mit-latex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. Based on the total number of pages dedicated to each book 1-chapter whose topic corresponds to the respective book I conclude that there is significant extra content in books 2-4 than in the respective chapters of book 1.

Comment: you can ask @Herbert himself he is usually around :)

Comment: I guess now it's too late but as a DANTE member you could have gotten massive discounts on the books listed here: http://www.dante.de/index/Literatur.html Einführung €25 instead of €29.95, Tabellen  €12 instead of €14.95, Mathematik €15 instead of €19.95, Bibliografien €14 instead of €16.95.

Comment: @HenriMenke: This was a while ago, but if I recall correctly, I researched the possibility of signing up with DANTE, but an address in Germany was required, which I don't have. In fact, if I had such an address, I would have purchased the electronic versions from Lehmann; instead I had to pay a little fortune not only for the books, but also for shipment and to have them scanned.

Comment: @EvanAad For the DANTE membership you do not need a German address.  The [membership form](http://www.dante.de/index/Intern/Mitglied/AntragOnline.html) has a field for country.  To order the books with DANTE discount you have to email the office anyway, so they will tell you what's the extra shipping cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Einführung* is meant as a comprehensive introduction to as many topics possible in the world of LaTeX, and can be viewed as a roadmap, whereas the other titles delve much deeper into a specific theme, offering alternative solutions, more background information and more case-studies and troubleshoots. The introduction contains only a portion of the other books, whereas the other books always contain everything that has been said in the introduction.

Maybe it is of some further interest to say something about the structure of the series, at least how I see it, and share some user-experience from the viewpoint of a noob.

One can also add to the list an introduction to LuaLaTeX, the comprehensive manual of `PStricks` and a LaTeX-Reference (all by Herbert Voß), the fantastic printed version of the KOMA-Script-guide by Markus Kohm, "TeX by Topic" by Victor Eijkhout, and a book on METAPOST-graphics by Walter Entenmann (appeared just recently; I don't know it though, as I rely on `PSTricks`).

In the case of bibliographies it has been helpful for me to first consult the *Einführung*, and whenever the explanations provided weren´t enough, to then consult the specific book on bibliographies and the internet. In the case of *Tabellen* I used the specific book directly, as I already had some very specific questions and was interested and not forced as in the case of bibliographies. The same approach has been useful for me with `PSTricks`.

The series is somewhat growing and the different titles are being constantly updated. They have proven very valuable for someone like me, who is relatively new to LaTeX and seeks help, and who is often confused by conflicting approaches, coming from different times and different people.